# Replacing a list of indices with a string in python

Tags: python, list

I have a set of indices in a list:

```
[2 0 3 4 5]
```

And I want to replace them by values stored in another list:

```
[a b c d e f g]
```

And output:

```
[c a d e f]
```

I tried this code:

```
for line in indices:
    print(line)
    for value in line:
        value = classes[value]
    print(line)
    break
```

which prints the original list twice. Is there a way to replace the elements or am I forced to create a new list of lists?

Comment: Of course it's printing the list twice, you have _two_ calls to `print`. What do you mean by "replacing the elements"? you don't want to do that! leave the input lists alone, and simply create a new one with the answer, as shown in my solution.

Comment: Well, I wanted it to print the original list and then the new list, rather than the original twice. So it sounds like, yes, I have to create a second list.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a good place to use a list comprehension, try this - the idiomatic solution:

```
idxs  = [2, 0, 3, 4, 5]
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

[chars[i] for i in idxs]
=> ['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Of course, we could do the same using explicit looping as you intended, but it's not as cool as the previous solution:

```
ans = []
for i in idxs:
    value = chars[i]
    ans.append(value)

ans
=> ['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

And as a final alternative - I don't know why you want to "replace the elements" in the input list (as stated in the question), but sure, that's also possible, but not recommended - it's simpler and cleaner to just create a new list with the answer (as shown in the two previous snippets), instead of changing the original input:

```
for pos, val in enumerate(idxs):
    idxs[pos] = chars[val]

idxs
=> ['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
idxs  = [2, 0, 3, 4, 5]
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
map(lambda x : chars[x],idxs)
=> ['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Or

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+[chars[y]],idxs,[])
=> ['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) function which converts int to characters(ascii table)

```
>>> a = [2 0 3 4 5]
>>> [chr(i+97) for i in a]
['c', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: values in `a` are just indices